# How many products of two single digits $x,y$ end in a specific digit $n$ in a given base $b$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, totient-function

While one can use brute force (i.e. counting a multiplication table) to see that e.g. in base ten  there are 27 combinations yielding zero ($0\cdot n, 2n\cdot 5$ and the other way around, counting $0^2$ only once), 4 for 1, 12 for 2 and so on,

is there a general formula for the amount $\phi_n(b)$ of products $n\equiv x\cdot y \pmod b$ with $n,x,y\in\{0,1,2,...,b-1\}$?

---

To add some numbers (from http://oeis.org/A095026) $\newcommand{\p}{\color{green}}$:

$$\begin{array}{r|rrrrrrrrrrr}
b\backslash n& 0& 1&   2&   3&   4&   5&   6&   7&   8&   9&  10&  11&  12&
\\\hline   1&     1&
\\ \p2&   \p3& \p1&
\\ \p3&   \p5& \p2& \p2&
\\   4&     8&   2&   4&   2&
\\ \p5&   \p9& \p4& \p4& \p4& \p4&
\\   6&    15&   2&   6&   5&   6&   2&
\\ \p7&\p{13}& \p6& \p6& \p6& \p6& \p6& \p6&
\\   8&    20&   4&   8&   4&  12&   4&   8&   4&
\\   9&    21&   6&   6&  12&   6&   6&  12&   6&   6&
\\  10&    27&   4&  12&   4&  12&   9&  12&   4&  12&   4&
\\\p{11}&\p{21}&\p{10}&\p{10}&\p{10}&\p{10}&\p{10}&\p{10}&\p{10}&\p{10}&\p{10}&\p{10}&
\\  12&    40&   4&   8&  10&  16&   4&  20&   4&  16&  10&   8&   4
\\\p{13}&\p{25}&\p{12}&\p{12}&\p{12}&\p{12}&\p{12}&\p{12}&\p{12}&\p{12}&\p{12}&\p{12}&\p{12}&\p{12}
\end{array}$$

As Thomas Andrews [commented](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/482950/how-many-products-of-two-single-digits-x-y-end-in-a-specific-digit-n-in-a-gi#comment1039946_482950), investigating upon prime bases and powers thereof looks like a good starting point, as the table shows $N(0)=2p-1$ and $N(n\neq0)=p-1$ for primes $p\le13$, while prime powers (4 and 9) show some periodic behaviour and general composites get more complicated.

Comment: Basic idea: First solve for $b=p^k$ for some prime $p$ and then use Chinese remainder theorem to get the more general answer.

Comment: I see http://oeis.org/A095026 basically describes this but lists no formula

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Hm, for 2;3;5 I get 3,1; 5,2,2; 9,4,4,4,4. So for $b=p$ a first guess would be $N(n\neq 0)=p−1$ and $N(0) = 2p-1$. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: There probably isn't a simple formula - certainly no closed formula. For $(n,b)=1$, the formula is $\phi(b)$. Gonna get messy after that, however.

Comment: But, for example, there are three solutions to $xy\equiv 0\pmod {2}$ and nine solutions ot $xy\equiv0\pmod 5$. So there are $27=3\cdot 9$ solutuons to $xy\equiv 0\pmod{10}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $\phi_n(b)$ to be the number of distinct solutions, modulo $b$, to $xy\equiv n\pmod b$. This notation is justified because $\phi_1(b)=\phi(b)$, the usual Euler totient function.

By Chinese Remainder theorem, we see that if $b=b_1b_2$, with $(b_1,b_2)=1$, then:

$$\phi_n(b)=\phi_n(b_1)\phi_n(b_2)$$

So $\phi_n$ is a multiplicative function.

If $(n,b)=1$, we can quickly see that $\phi_n(b)=\phi(b)$. Also, if we have $(m,b)=1$ then $\phi_{mn}(b)=\phi_n(b)$.

This means that we only need to solve $\phi_{p^i}(p^k)$ for $1\leq i\leq k$.

I can prove that $$\phi_{p^i}(p^k)=(i+1)\phi(p^k), \,0\leq i<k$$

The case $i=k$ is messier. It is easy to show that $\phi_p(p)=2p-1$. Experimental data seems to indicate that we have:

$$\phi_{p^k}(p^k) = \phi(p^k)(k+1) + p^{k-1}$$
I haven't had time to try to prove this.

Comment: $\phi_{n\neq0}(p)=p-1$ should also be clear: $\phi_0(p)=\phi_p(p)=2p-1$ (since only $0\cdot y\equiv 0 \pmod p$ in a prime base), and the multiples of $0<x<p-1$ are permutations of $(0,1,2,...,p-1)$, all $\phi_{n\neq0}(p)=\phi_{m\neq0}(p)$. Since there are $p^2$ products possible and there are $p-1$ digits $\neq0$, we have $$\phi_{n\neq0}(p) = \frac{p^2-\phi_0(p)}{p-1} = p-1$$

Comment: Yeah, that case follows since $n\not\equiv 0\pmod p$ means $(n,p)=1$ so $\phi_n(p)=\phi(p)=p-1$ @TobiasKienzler

Comment: Yes, that would have been easier to see [m-/](http://picardfacepalm.com/) Great generalization of $\phi$ by the way! So $\phi_n(b)$ seems to be easier to determine for bases where prime factors occur only once than for prime powers...

Comment: Yes, for square-free $b$, it is easier.

Comment: I think when $0\leq i<k$, we get $\phi_{p^i}(p^k)=(i+1)\phi(p^k)$. The case of $i=k$ is the messy one.

Comment: Interesting update, we're getting closer :) I also found $\phi_0(b)$ might be http://oeis.org/A018804, "Pillai's arithmetical function: sum of gcd(k, b) for 1 <= k <= b", i.e. $$\phi_0(b) = \sum_{k=1}^b \gcd(k,b)$$

Comment: Yeah, I was talking about your simplification of Pillai's function for $n=p^k$, not the summation formula. Pillai might well be $\phi_0(b)$, haven't had time to toss around the idea.

Comment: Ok, it's not as simple as I hoped... $\gcd(n,p^k) = p^l$ where $l<k$ is the smallest value such that $\gcd(n p^{-l},p)=1$, so I don't see how the sum can be simplified "easily". Your experimental result looks fine so far though

Comment: I didn't find a nice simplification to show whether your $\phi_0(p^k)$ is equivalent to Pillai's function, but I think I did find [kind of a formula for the general $\phi_n(b)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/485171/163).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here's an approach that hopefully complements Thomas Andrews' one:

Observing the sequence $k\cdot l \bmod b$ for fixed $k,b$, i.e.
$$0, k, 2k\bmod b, 3k\bmod b, ..., (b-1)k\bmod b$$
notice that it has a period of $b/\gcd(k,b)$ (since $b|(bk/(b,k))$) and therefore repeats the digits 
$$0,k,2k\bmod b,...,\left(\frac{b}{(k,b)}-1\right)\cdot k\bmod b$$
$(k,b)$ times, while the other digits do not occur for that $k$. So by defining
$$\mu_{k,n}(b)=\begin{cases}1 & (k,b)\mid n \\ 0 & \text{else} \end{cases}$$
to denote whether there exists an $l<b$ for which $k\cdot l\equiv n\pmod b$, we therefore obtain
$$\boxed{\begin{align}
  \phi_n(b) &= \sum\limits_{k=1}^b \mu_{k,n}(b)\cdot(k,b)
        \\  &\stackrel{\text{T.A.}}= \sum_{d\mid (n,b)} d\cdot \phi\left(\frac bd\right)
\end{align}}$$
where the latter form is [courtesy of Thomas Andrews](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/482950/how-many-products-of-two-single-digits-x-y-end-in-a-specific-digit-n-in-a-gi#comment1044452_485171). As [he also showed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/482950/how-many-products-of-two-single-digits-x-y-end-in-a-specific-digit-n-in-a-gi#comment1044479_485171), this function is multiplicative, i.e.
$$\phi_n(b_1\cdot b_2) = \phi_n(b_1)\cdot\phi_n(b_2)\quad\text{for }(b_1,b_2)=1.$$

Note how this especially yields the mentioned identities

$$\begin{align}\phi_1(b) &= \sum\limits_{k=1 \\ (k,b)=1}^b 1 = \text{"the" } \phi(b),
\\\phi_0(b) &= \sum\limits_{k=1}^b (k,b),\quad(\mu_{k,0}\equiv1\text{ since anything divides zero})\end{align}$$
i.e. $\phi_0(b)$ is [Pillai's arithmetical function](http://oeis.org/A018804) while $\phi_1(b)$ is [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).

For prime bases $p$, one obtains [aforementioned](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/482950/how-many-products-of-two-single-digits-x-y-end-in-a-specific-digit-n-in-a-gi#comment1039965_482950)
$$\begin{align}
  \phi_0(p) &= \sum_{k=1}^p\underbrace{(k,p)}_{=\begin{cases}1 & k\neq p\\p & k=p\end{cases}} = 2p-1,
\\\phi_{n\neq0}(p) &= \phi(p) = p-1
\end{align}$$

For prime powers refer to [Thomas Andrews' answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/482971/163).

Comment: I'll try to look tomorrow. Should that be $\mu_{k,n}(b)$? Looks like you mean product of $kn$, but the definition doesn't agree with that.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Ah no, that should be two separate indices indeed - I'm a lazy Physicist, sorry :7

Comment: Note that you can re-arrange $$\sum_{k=1}^b\gcd(k,b) = \sum_{d\mid b} \sum_{k=1}_{(k,b/d)=1}^{b/d} d = \sum_{d\mid b} d\phi(b/d)$$
Essentially, we enumerate over possible $d=(k,b)$ and then enumerate the appropriate $k$.

Comment: Why if $n\mid k$ are we counting the products? I think $\mu_{k,n}$ is almost but not quite right.

Comment: For example, if $n=4, k=6, b=8$, we can get $2k\equiv n\pmod 8$ so we'd want $\mu_{6,4}(8)=1$. On the other hand, you want $\mu_{4,2}(8)=0$, since there is no way for $2\equiv 4x\pmod 8$

Comment: I think you want $\mu_{k,n}(b)=1$ exactly when $(k,b)\mid n$. The case $n=0$ still works exactly as claimed, however. As does $n=1$.

Comment: I think the actual close formula can be written as $$\phi_n(b)=\sum_{d|(b,n)} d\phi\left(\frac{b}{d}\right)$$ For example, if $(b,n)=1$ then we get $\phi_n(b)=\phi(b)$ and if $n=b$ then $\phi_b(b)$ is the formula that I gave above which agrees with your formula.

Comment: This formula also gives us the one I conjectured before: $$\phi_{0}(p^k)=p^k + k\phi(p^k) = p^{k-1} + (k+1)\phi(p^k)$$

Comment: We can see my formula is multiplicative by defining $f_n(d)=1$ if $d\mid n$ and $f_n(d)=0$ otherwise. Then $f_n(d)$ is multiplicative, since if $d_1\mid n$ and $d_2\mid n$ and $(d_1,d_2)=1$ then we know $d_1d_2\mid n$. The above is $$\sum_{d\mid b}df_n(d)\phi(b/d)$$ which is the Dirichlet convolution of two multiplicative functions, $\phi$ and $df_n(d)$, so is also multiplicative.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Awesome comments, thanks a lot! I edited in the fix, the formula looks good. Though to calculate $\phi_n(b)$ it is probably easier to use its being multiplicative, the prime factorization of $b$ and your power laws.

Comment: I think your expression for $\phi_1(b)$ is wrong - it should be $$\sum_{k=1}_{(k,b)=1}^b 1$$You have $$\sum_{k\not\mid n} 1$$ which is wrong most obviously because there is no $n$ on the LHS.

Comment: One last check of the formula, you can show that $\sum_{n=1}^b \phi_n(b) = b^2$ with the above formulas. It's a little easier for my version of the expression for $\phi_n(b)$, since we know that $\sum_{d|n}\phi(d) = n$.

Comment: It should have been $\sum_{k\not\mid b}$ but that was still based on my wrong $\mu_{k,n}(b)$ anyway, I forgot to update it. Thanks for your continued feedback!

Comment: Your welcome. I really liked this problem.